# Show that $G$ has a $K_3$-free subgraph with $|E|/2$ edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

This is a question from an old exam and I don't know how to do c).

Let $n$ be an even number and let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $n\geq 4$.

a) Draw a $K_3$ graph with $n^2/4$ edges.

b) Show that $G$ has a $K_3$ if $\delta(G) > n/2$.

c) Show that $G$ has a $K_3$-free subgraph with $|E|/2$ edges.

---

a) is just a square

For b) we had a theorem that says that  the maximum number of edges in a $K_3$-free graph is $\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \right\rfloor$. The sum of all degrees is equal to twice the number of edges, we get $2\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \right\rfloor$ = $\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{2} \right\rfloor$. $\delta(G) > n/2$ is the minimal degree a vertex, so all vertices are $n^2/2$.

Comment: In (a) by "a $K_3$ graph" I think you meant "a $K_3$-free graph."

Comment: For (b), instead in quoting the Mantel's or Turán's theorem, you can give a short simple direct proof. Let $u,v$ be two adjacent vertices. If the graph is $K_3$-free, then $u$ and $v$ have no common neighbor, so $\deg(u)+\deg(v)\le n$. Since $\deg(u)+\deg(v)\ge2\delta(G)$, it follows that $\delta(G)\le n/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Instead of trying to find any $K_3$-free subgraph with $|E|/2$ edges try to find a **bipartite** subgraph with $|E|/2$ edges. To do this there are several ways, including an elegant probabilistic one. I suggest you try it yourself.

Comment: It's plain to see that, if we take a bipartite subgraph of $G$ with the maximum number of edges, then it must contain at least half the edges of $G$, for if it didn't we could could get a bigger bipartite graph by moving one vertex to the other side. The probabilistic argument is more elegant than that?

Comment: @bof Did I write anywhere that the probabilistic argument is **the most** elegant of all?